# Using Liquid custom tags to output multiple `span` elements`

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm playing with Jekyll plugins and their ability to create custom tags and I've run into an issue extending my tag to accept a comma separated list.

I started with the following:

```
{% symbol R %}
```

And the matching plugin code:

```
module Jekyll
  class Symbol < Liquid::Tag
    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
      @text = text
    end 

    def render(context)
      "<span class='symbol-#{@text}'>#{@text}</span>"
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('symbol', Jekyll::Symbol)
```

And the output on my page, as expected, is:

```
<span class="symbol-R">R</span>
```

What I'm trying to do now is amend this plugin so I can pass in a comma separated list, for example:

```
{% symbol R,G %}
```

I updated my plugin code to this:

```
module Jekyll
  class Symbol < Liquid::Tag
    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
      @text = text
    end 

    def render(context)
      symbol = @text.split(',').map(&:strip)

      symbol.each do |item|
        puts item # to test in terminal
        "<span class='symbol-#{@text}'>#{@text}</span>"
      end
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('symbol', Jekyll::Symbol)
```

Terminal outputs correctly:

```
R
G
```

And my expectation was that I'd get the following on my page:

```
<span class="symbol-R">R</span><span class="symbol-G">G</span>
```

But all that shows up on the page is:

```
RG
```

Could I get some help in figuring this out? I feel like I'm super close... it's just the actual page rendering I'm clearly messing up on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby your function will return the last expression that it executed. For you, this is the `symbol.each do … end`.

[`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) returns various things, but what it does not do by itself is return the contents of its block. For that, you want [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
symbol.map do |item|
  puts item # to test in terminal
  "<span class='symbol-#{@text}'>#{@text}</span>"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
symbol.each do |item|
  puts item # to test in terminal
  "<span class='symbol-#{@text}'>#{@text}</span>"
end
```

by

```
output = ""
symbol.each do |item|
  output =+ "<span class='symbol-#{item}'>#{item}</span>"
end

output
```